# Fancybox flash parameters

Tags: html, flash, fancybox

I am using fancybox within a html page and I am calling an flv file via a swf file, plays fine locally and works via the web, the problem is that I need to link all of my assets with remote urls as I need to host the html elsewhere. So html hosted on server A and assets on server B. So my thoughts turn to adding the flash parameter  to the query.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js file and this is where I get stuck.

http://www.myofficeheadset.com/video.html

I've located the object tag in the query.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js file I just need to add the allowScriptAccess parameter

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="'+e.width+'" height="'+e.height+'"><param name="movie" value="'+c+
'"></param>';P="";b.each(e.swf,function(x,H){C+='<param name="'+x+'" value="'+H+'"></param>';P+=" "+x+'="'+H+'"'});C+='<embed src="'+c+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="'+e.width+'" height="'+e.height+'"'+P+"></embed></object>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Justin

Answer (score 1):

Using the video player within Flash usually loads the movie content dynamically from another location or file. It seems like the flash is loading perfectly fine, but it can not find the movie to load. You should make the path to this movie inside the swf an absolute path, as the relative directory changes based on where the swf is loaded into.

Comment: Hi There,

I have already placed in absolute links to all assets including the swf file, I have now placed the swf on another server to the flv and the swf file works, it seems the html call is not working.

SWF
http://www.myofficeheadset.com/BelieveContactCentre.swf

HTML
http://www.myofficeheadset.com/video.html